# full-text search on in-memory business objects

Tags: .net, search, wildcard, in-memory

I would like to ask for advice on best-practices concerning search on in-memory objects.

Our business data is represented as in memory C# objects. It is explicitly specified which properties of the objects should be matched. I supposed to be able to select those business objects that match to a search-phrase where the search-phrase may contain wildcards (no boolean operations). I have full control on the entire code.

How would you implement search in this case?

Comment: I'd recommend lucene.net everytime for FTS

Comment: How many objects and how often do they change?  Lucene.NET is fantastic and I'd definitely recommend it. However, if you have lots of rapidly changing objects then it'd probably take too long to build the index (but still worth experimenting with).